# How to get a week ago as UTC timestamp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

How can I get a UTC timestamp of a week ago in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (i.e., YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ) using JavaScript?

I don't want to use any libraries.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standard Date functions:

```js
const d = new Date();

d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);

console.log(d.toISOString());
```